# How can I change the owner of a file in Windows (command line)

Tags: windows, batch-file, file-ownership

I am working in Windows with a non-admin-account.
Sometimes I have files which I am not allowed to write. These files are from another user with admin rights which I use to install software.

How can I change the owner of a file inside the command line (cmd)?
In Linux it would be easy with the command `chown`. Is there a similar command in Windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the ownership of a file to User "Michael":
`icacls file.txt /setowner "Michael"`

Change the ownership of a file to the currently logged in user:
`takeown /f file.txt`

More Details can be found here:
https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/take-ownership-of-file-or-folder/